# Are There Other Characters Like Ampersand in XML Format Which Need To be Converted

Tags: xml, validation, rss, xml-serialization, feed

While I was writing a custom RSS feed for my PHP program, I've come across an issue that the ampersand (&) character has to be converted to `&amp;`. I'm wondering if there are other characters like this. Thanks for your information.

This is invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>         
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>custom user feed</title>                 
        <item>
            <description>
                <div>a & b</div>
            </description>
        </item>
</channel>      
</rss>
```

Reference: [Why can't RSS handle the ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030102/why-cant-rss-handle-the-ampersand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at a bare minimum, it should be obvious that `<` will cause you issues, since it would be taken as a tag start. It is usually encoded as `&lt;`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping for more detail.

Comment: Not only "usually": `The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section.` see [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax)

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for such a quick reply and the information. I tried this `<div>a &amp; b &lt; c > "d" 'e'</div>` and it seems that double and single quotes and `>` are okay to be used without not escaping. So `&` and `<` are all I need to care about?

Comment: @fvu, I agree with you. I was just saying that it was usually encoded in that way, not that it can sometimes be in there as the literal `<` character. I think there are also other encodings that aren't literal `<` but still give the same result, such as the numeric character reference.

Comment: @Teno, those are the two key syntax markers that are forbidden. Most of the others are conveniences rather than dictates.

Comment: @paxdiablo indeed - `If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " &amp; " and " &lt; " respectively.`  (XML spec).